# How to check a list contains substring from other list using scala?

Tags: list, scala

I have following lists-

```
A = List(("192.168.20.1", "WinInfra",           List("naa.6d867d9c7ac")), 
         ("192.168.20.1", "TriSQLFreshInstall", List("naa.6d867d",
                                                     "naa.42704fdc4")), 
         ("192.168.20.1", "redHat7",            List("naa.4270cdf",
                                                     "naa.427045dc")))

B = List("4270cdf", "427045dc", "42704fdc4")
```

I want to check if last element of list A (it is a list of strings) contains any substring from list B and get output as unmatched elements only.

**Edit:** I want to check if any element of list B is exist in list A and collect only such list elements from list A which do not contains list B elements.

I want following output-

```
List(("192.168.20.1","WinInfra",List( "naa.6d867d9c7ac")))
```

How do I get above output using scala??

Comment: could you please reduce the data samples to simpler ones, i.e. remove all fields but one, and replace the long strings with dummy ones that are easy to read?

Comment: @ErikAllik- i reduced fields. Can you please check and let me know if anything not clear??

Comment: Isn't it about time you worked some of these out for yourself? You've asked dozens of rather similar questions over the last few months, surely you must have learnt something from that and find it quicker to solve it yourself?

Comment: println("""List(("192.168.20.1","WinInfra",List( "naa.6d867d9c7ac")))""")

Answer (score 2):

I think something like this:

```
A.filterNot(a => B.exists(b => a._3.exists(str => str.contains(b))))
```

or

```
A.filterNot(a => a._3.exists(str => B.exists(b => str.contains(b))))
```

or shorter, but less readable

```
A.filterNot(_._3 exists (B exists _.contains))
```

Answer (score 2):

First, I wouldn't pass around tuples. It would be a lot easier if you would put this data structure into an object and work with that. However, it would be easier start by finding matches first. So you'll start out by applying a filter on List A:

```
A.filter { (ip, disc, sublist) => .... }
```

Where items in your sublist items are in List B:

```
sublist.exists(sublistItem => b.contains(sublistItem.replaceAll("naa.", "")))
```

This returns:

```
res1: List[(String, String, List[String])] = List((192.168.20.1,TriSQLFreshInstall,List(naa.6d867d, naa.42704fdc4)), (192.168.20.1,redHat7,List(naa.4270cdf, naa.427045dc)))
```

Which is the opposite of what you want. This is easy to correct by saying filterNot:

```
A.filterNot { (ip, disc, sublist) => sublist.exists(sublistItem => b.contains(sublistItem.replaceAll("naa.", ""))) }
```